# Device with fake IMEI number that doesn't belong to me is shown under my Google Dashboard

Tags: google, imei

I have sync my google account on my samsung galaxy note 2 but recently i have lost it.

After few days when i was checking google dash board to recover my contacts, i saw 2 devices listed under my Android.

One device GT-N7100 is my own device whereas N7000 with fake imei (231961768368404) does not belong to me.

How is it possible.

I have given my phone for tracking by the police but now i am confused whether my handset imei is changed or it is showing someone else device under my google account.

Answer (score 2):

A very possible reason is probably you have used your Google Account in another mobile also for downloading apps from Google Play or for accessing Gmail or whatever. Don't panic about such things if you've logged out from that devices.

Answer (score 1):

### Theory #1

The device may represent an android emulator you used, where you installed an application on it through play store or simply logged into your google account.

### Theory #2

Devices never get deleted from google's database (even if you can hide them). This device may represent an old android  phone you had.

Comment: The last argument is flawed, since IMEI doesn't/shouldn't change when the phone is reset. The IMEI can be changed after the phone is rooted, and this doesn't always require a reset.

Comment: The IMEI should NEVER change, eve if you're rooted, since changing the IMEI is illegal in some countries, and can/will cause carriers to blacklist your device.

Comment: Wooops, you're right. When I reset my phone I was told by Titanium backup that something had changed. I thought it was the IMEI, but I didn't realise that it can be numeric only, while the one shown by Titanium Backup was alphanumeric.
Sorry and thanks for you feedback.